# Error using python pydot

Tags: python, ipython, theano, pydot

I get error using the theano.printing.pydotprint() function

following lines work fine without any error:

```
>>> from theano import *
>>> import theano.tensor as T
>>> import pydot
>>> import numpy
```

Also when I run

```
>>> theano.printing.pydotprint
```

in the python interpreter I get output as

```
<function pydotprint at 0x307ed70>
```

but the problem is when I execute the script using the function I get following error

```
RuntimeError: Failed to import pydot. You must install pydot for `pydotprint` to work.
```

Any idea what is the problem?

P.S: I am running the python tutorial given here:
http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/printing_drawing.html
So the call to the function is surely correct.

Here is the traceback of the error I am getting:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/utils/py3compat.pyc in execfile(fname, *where)
    173             else:
    174                 filename = fname
--> 175             __builtin__.execfile(filename, *where)

/home/abhishek/Desktop/Theano/test2.py in <module>()
     64 if not os.path.exists('pics'):
     65     os.mkdir('pics')
---> 66 theano.printing.pydotprint(predict,outfile="pics/logreg_pydotprint_predic.png",var_with_name_simple=True)
     67 # before compilation

     68 theano.printing.pydotprint_variables(prediction,outfile="pics/logreg_pydotprint_prediction.png",var_with_name_simple=True)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/printing.pyc in pydotprint(fct, outfile, compact, format, with_ids, high_contrast, cond_highlight, colorCodes, max_label_size, scan_graphs, var_with_name_simple, print_output_file, assert_nb_all_strings)
    566 
    567     if not pydot_imported:
--> 568         raise RuntimeError("Failed to import pydot. You must install pydot"
    569                             " for `pydotprint` to work.")
    570         return

RuntimeError: Failed to import pydot. You must install pydot for `pydotprint` to work.
```

Comment: add a traceback of the error

Comment: @flebool : I have added the error traceback.

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tried reinstalling pydot as given by the [solution to this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15951748/pydot-and-graphviz-error-couldnt-import-dot-parser-loading-of-dot-files-will), but this was not working.

That is

```
pip uninstall pyparsing
pip install -Iv https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pyparsing/pyparsing-1.5.7.tar.gz#md5=9be0fcdcc595199c646ab317c1d9a709
pip install pydot
```

there was some problem with this installation, even though every time, installed successfully message was given.

But

```
sudo apt-get install python-pydot
```

this worked.

"Because the solution was not to install pydot from somewhere, but "python-pydot" from official ubuntu repositories." - [answer by sadik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15951748/pydot-and-graphviz-error-couldnt-import-dot-parser-loading-of-dot-files-will) worked

We must note that on successful installation of pydot, it can be checked at two places.
/usr/share/doc/python-pydot
and
/usr/share/python-support/python-pydot

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Abhishek : Check if you could see the "pydot" folder under the lib folder. Looks like you are in *ix* machine. Ideally you would find it is installed or not within 'lib' folder / or within site-packages.

Meanwhile, I would suggest you to try re-installing the package(pydot) and see if it helps.

Comment: I tried reinstalling pydot along with pyparsing-1.5.7. But this doesn't solve the problem.

I dun have pydot folder neither in "/usr/lib"
or in "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages". 

But surprisingly "import pydot" command is working.

I have tried reinstallation many times, doesn't help.
Any other suggestion?

Comment: hey got it fixed!
The issue was somehow pip was not installing it correctly.

The solution was not to install pydot from somewhere, but "python-pydot" from official ubuntu repositories.