# Python: NameError: global name 'dot_parser' is not defined

Tags: python

Python is rather new to me.

I am trying to run the titanic machine learning example of the "Machine Learning in Python with Scikit" book. The classification with decision trees works fine (clf is defined properly) but if I want to visualize the decision tree (see code snippet below) I got the following error message (copied from IPython).

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-15b1b4a5d909> in <module>()
      3 dot_data = StringIO.StringIO()
      4 tree.export_graphviz(clf, out_file = dot_data, feature_names = ['PClass', 'AgeFill', 'Gender'])
----> 5 graph = pydot.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue())
      6 graph.write_png('titanic.png')

C:\Users\885299\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda32\lib\site-packages\pydot.pyc in graph_from_dot_data(data)

    218     """
    219 
--> 220     return dot_parser.parse_dot_data(data)
    221 
    222 
NameError: global name 'dot_parser' is not defined
```

Can somebody help me?

Code snippet that I used (similar to the book) was:

```
import pydot, StringIO

dot_data = StringIO.StringIO()
tree.export_graphviz(clf, out_file = dot_data, feature_names = ['Class', 'Age', 'Gender'])
graph = pydot.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue())
graph.write_png('titanic.png')

from IPython.core.display import Image
Image(filename = 'titanic.png')
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! I want to say thanks for putting together a well formed question. I would suggest that you leave out "Can somebody help me?" from future posts as it can be a bit of a red flag to many members of the SO community.  Otherwise, this looks like a solid question.

Comment: What package is ``dot_parser`` in? Have you imported it (like you've imported ``pydot`` and ``StringIO``)?

Answer (score 1):

In case you're using Python 3, using pydotplus instead of pydot worked fine for me.

[Here is the github repo](https://github.com/carlos-jenkins/pydotplus)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

There is what appears to be a [related issue](https://github.com/erocarrera/pydot/issues/54) on github. The recommendation is to ensure you "have installed the pyparser libraries and to update them." However, I'm pretty sure they mean the `pyparsing` library.

You can install pyparsing by running `pip install pyparsing`

You can update pyparsing by running `pip install -U pyparsing`

Additionally, a [related stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17902926/228489) that recommends uninstalling pyparsing and then reinstalling pyparsing and pydot.

Comment: Just a small question: On a Windows PC, should I just type pip install pyparsing on the command line? If so, in which directory?

Comment: `pip` doesn't come installed with python prior to python version 3.4. Here is a great [SO Post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12476379/228489) on how to install `pip` on windows.

Answer (score 0):

I also strongly recommend using pydotplus instead of pydot (seems there is a problem with pydot and Python3).

This blogpost helped me:
http://www.sas-programming.com/2015/04/sklearn-decisiontree-plot-example-needs.html

Answer (score 0):

I used the following and got it working with Python3. Pyparser 2.2.0 is compatible with pydot.

```
pip install pyparsing==2.2.0
pip install pydot
```

This installed pydot 1.2.3.

If you have any prior installed pydot packages, first uninstall them with `pip uninstall pydot` and do a fresh installation as in above steps.

Answer (score 0):

Great solutions thanks. I had the same issue on Ubuntu 14.04. Just few words: when i try to uninstall pyparsing and pydot i had a error:

Not uninstalling pydot at /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages, owned by OS

i solved upgrading pip with 

`sudo pip install --upgrade pip`

and then following the below commands:

`sudo -H pip uninstall pydot
sudo -H pip uninstall pyparsing`

and reinstalling:

`sudo -H pip install pyparsing
sudo -H pip install pydot`