# Python 3 networkx draw_graphviz() does not work

Tags: python-3.x, graphviz, networkx

I just want to draw a simple graph with Python 3 networkx & graphviz:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.complete_graph(3)
nx.draw_graphviz(G)
```

I'm using ubuntu14.04 and IPython3 and as usual I did pip3 install networkx and running the code gave me:

```
ImportError: pydot could not be loaded: http://code.google.com/p/pydot/
```

And I tried installing pydotplus and running the code:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/networkx/drawing/nx_pydot.py in pydot_layout(G, prog, root, **kwds)
    294 
    295         if isinstance(node,list):
--> 296             node=node[0]
    297         pos=node.get_pos()[1:-1] # strip leading and trailing double quotes
    298         if pos != None:

IndexError: list index out of range
```

and pydot2 also:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pydot.py in write(self, path, prog, format)
   1893             prog = self.prog
   1894 
-> 1895         dot_fd = file(path, "w+b")
   1896         if format == 'raw':
   1897             data = self.to_string()

NameError: name 'file' is not defined
```

I spent quite some time searching and installing other pydots and pygraphviz combinations already but still no luck.

While this may be related:
[pydot and graphviz error: Couldn't import dot_parser, loading of dot files will not be possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15951748/pydot-and-graphviz-error-couldnt-import-dot-parser-loading-of-dot-files-will), that doesn't solve the problem in Python 3.

Comment: Does this https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pygraphviz-discuss/mbK5voZ9-hs explain some of the issue?

Comment: I think pygraphviz depends on parsing of the [DOT language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_%28graph_description_language%29)  which is the job of pydot? And now somehow it is pydot that is incompatible with Python3 rather than pygraphviz.

Comment: FWIW, I achieved the desired result by outputting a .dot file using `networkx.write_dot(G, 'graph.dot')` and then do the appropriate graphviz output command like `neato -T png graph.dot > graph.png`. (graphviz has to be installed beforehand; see the man page for more)

Comment: You might add that as an answer.  Others with the same problem may not check the comments.

Comment: Some additional information: pygraphviz now claims to work with Python 3 right now but as of this moment I install it using the source by running `python3 setup.py install`, and `import pygraphviz` in Python3 gives me `ImportError: No module named '_graphviz'`.

Comment: Also the ubuntu package here does not work as well: http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/python3-pygraphviz-dbg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix this by editing the line `#292` from:

```
    pydot_node = pydot.Node(make_str(n)).get_name().encode('utf-8')
```

to remove the encode at the end:

```
    pydot_node = pydot.Node(make_str(n)).get_name() #.encode('utf-8')
```

I've reported this bug/fix [here](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/issues/1836).

Comment: It does resolve the error when using pydotplus in this case :). But I still can't see the matplotlib window popup?

Comment: @pterodragon Is matplotlib in interactive mode? You might need to do a `plt.show()` to get the window to appear.

Comment: I thought it will show automatically. Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be the same issue as that the pydot you're using is a version incompatible with Python 3, which uses file(...). file(...) is removed in Python 3 already.

I noticed this issue and setup a Python 3 compatible version on PyPi.

For Linux systems for Python 3.x, try:

`pip3 install pydot3`

Or in general for Python 2.x, try:

`pip install pydot3`

Answer (score 1):

Not a very great answer but it acts as a workaround.

First output the .dot file by
`networkx.write_dot(G, 'graph.dot')` using Python

and then do the appropriate graphviz output command like `neato -T png graph.dot > graph.png` on the command line.