# NameError: global name 'dot_parser' is not defined

Tags: python, python-2.7, scikit-learn, pyparsing, pydot

I was playing with the decision tree algorithm and trying to plot the tree. However the IDE reported following error:

```
Couldn't import dot_parser, loading of dot files will not be possible.
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Users/s152730/Desktop/exe1.py", line 70, in <module>
        graph = pydot.graph_from_dot_data(test.getvalue())
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pydot.py", line 220, in graph_from_dot_data
        return dot_parser.parse_dot_data(data)
    NameError: global name 'dot_parser' is not defined
```

I have no idea how to deal with this problem because I've tried to uninstall and reinstall both pydot dan pyparsing, which was proposed in other answers, but it didn't help.

Here is my code:

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.tree import ExtraTreeClassifier
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn.externals.six import StringIO
import pydot
from IPython.display import Image

test = StringIO()
tree.export_graphviz(clf, out_file=test, feature_names = attribute_names)
graph = pydot.graph_from_dot_data(test.getvalue())
graph.writepng('test.png')
image(filename = 'test.png')
```

I am using python2.7 and running on PyCharm, the OS is win8.1.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is there a stacktrace? Or perhaps whittle down the code until you get what is called a [mcve]. This will help isolate the problem.

Comment: Just update the stacktrace. I am completely confused how to address this problem. Could you please help me?

Comment: First of all, try creating a [mcve] by isolating parts of your code until you isolate the exact lines/modules/packages creating the problem. The Stacktrace already helps, because now we know that it is a problem when calling the `pydot.graph_from_dot_data` method.

Comment: try: pip install pydot2

Answer (score 3):

It seems your error is that you are missing part of a library (`pyparsing`) because of incorrect order of installation.

See [here](https://github.com/erocarrera/pydot/issues/81) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15951748/pydot-and-graphviz-error-couldnt-import-dot-parser-loading-of-dot-files-will)

> Obvious to the initiated but not to the newbie: The workaround is to
>   install  pyparsing < 2.0.0 prior to installing pydot (or a package
>   that depends on  pydot.)
>
> $ pip install pyparsing==1.5.7

The solution seems to be to first remove `pydot` and `pyparsing`, and then to install `pyparsing` first, then `pydot`.

The versions of which to install will most likely change in the future, so at the moment it seems you need to run something like the following: (taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17902926/1561176) lovely answer)

```
pip uninstall pyparsing
pip install -Iv https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pyparsing/pyparsing-1.5.7.tar.gz#md5=9be0fcdcc595199c646ab317c1d9a709
pip install pydot
```

Comment: @Tanasis Is that so? I never had that issue, do you have a source to cite?

Comment: After I did `pip uninstall pyparsing`, `pip install` would complain about not finding `pyparsing` and would not work. I hope I will find the time to reproduce this and paste you the error, but I am crazy busy these days. :(

Comment: As of today, there's no need to install pyparsing < 2.0.0 (otherwise you'll encounter the "module pyparsing not found" error). Just uninstall both of them and then install pyparsing first and then pydot, without paying attention to the actual release version.

Answer (score 2):

For me, I found a  great tip is to install [pydotplus](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pydotplus) instead, as it is compatible with pyparsing v2.0 and greater. It also has the advantage that it can work with the graphviz installation from Anaconda. I'm using Anaconda v2.4.1 and on Windows 7 x64 and Graphviz 2.38 installed using condas.

Answer (score 2):

I've just update my `pydot`to `1.2.3`, and the error disappears.

```
sudo pip install -U pydot
```