# Couldn't import dot_parser, loading of dot files will not be possible

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7

**Before marking it duplicate, please read it fully.**

I am trying to use pydot in my script which depends on pyparsing module. But the module I have is pyparsing 2.0.1 which came with the MAC installation. This needs to be downgraded to 1.5.7 to fix this error - "Couldn't import dot_parser, loading of dot files will not be possible" as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15951748/pydot-and-graphviz-error-couldnt-import-dot-parser-loading-of-dot-files-will), but when I tried to uninstall my existing pyparsing module, I am getting this error -

```
pip uninstall pyparsing
DEPRECATION: Uninstalling a distutils installed project (pyparsing) has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. This is due to the fact that uninstalling a distutils project will only partially uninstall the project.
Uninstalling pyparsing-2.0.1:
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pyparsing-2.0.1-py2.7.egg-info
Proceed (y/n)?
```

If I give yes, as expected, this is throwing me Operation not permitted error due to the System Integrity Protection in Mac OS X. So I am not able to proceed with this.

I tried to see my module path,

```
import site; site.getsitepackages()
['/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']
```

I can see pyparsing 2.0.1 under my site-packages as well, Is there a way to uninstall that alone without modifying the pyparsing under system library?

Comment: You talk about uninstalling pyparsing, but it sounds like you want to *upgrade* pyparsing?

Comment: I dont want to upgrade, if you see the link I tried to follow, thats the solution provided for the error I receive, it says to uninstall the latest version 2.0.1 and install 1.5.7 to fix this issue. Updated the question to make it clear.

Comment: `/Library/Python/` does not cause problems altering (e.g., it's not under Mac's SIP)?

Comment: Yeah I know. Thats why I am asking is there a way to uninstall pyparsing under /Library/Python alone? Because when i specify pip uninstall pyparsing, its automatically trying to uninstall pyparsing under system library. If you see the error I am getting.

Comment: NB: the second answer in your linked question suggests using pydot2 instead. That avoids downgrading. Why can't you use that?

Comment: I tried that as well, it was throwing me some other error, but your solution with user worked like a charm. Now I could convert dot to png using pydot. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install it as a user package (which goes somewhere in `$HOME/Library`). 
This should take precedence over system installed packages, and you don't need to adjust your PYTHONPATH.

```
pip install pyparsing==1.5.7 --user
```

---

As an aside, you remove pyparsing from `/Library/Python` manually:

```
rm -r /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pyparsing*
```

But that shouldn't matter with the above solution.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot for your help. I did use the first one with --user, it worked.

Comment: Note that pyparsing 1.5.7 is not Python3-compatible