# How can I completely reinstall Django on a Mac

Tags: python, django, terminal

I'm a complete newcomer to Python and the Django framework so please be gentle.

I'm on a Mac 10.8 and MAMP. I was following the tutorial and installed the latest stable version (1.5) of Django using pip thanks to the instructions on this page. For some reason, I decided immediately after this to install instead the development version (1.6dev) by cloning the git repository using these instructions. At this point, everything was OK and running the following code:

```
>>> import django
>>> print(django.get_version())
```

printed out version 1.6dev-blahblahblah.

I then tried to create my first project with this command:

```
django-admin.py startproject mysite
```

It worked. Here's where I did something stupid. I changed my mind at this point and thought it might be better to stick with the stable development version rather than the bleeding edge version and so I tried to remove the development version. All I did was delete the django folder found after typing this command:

```
python -c "import sys; sys.path = sys.path[1:]; import django; print(django.__path__)"
```

I then reran pip and it said everything was installed correctly. When I get the version number from the Python interpreter I get this output:

```
>>> import django
>>> print(django.get_version())
1.5.1
```

However, when I try to create a new project I get the following error:

```
django-admin.py startproject mysite
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/django-admin.py", line 4, in <module>
from pkg_resources import require; require('Django==1.6.dev20130425172216')
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 2607, in <module>
parse_requirements(__requires__), Environment()
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 565, in resolve
raise DistributionNotFound(req)  # XXX put more info here
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: Django==1.6.dev20130425172216
Garrys-MacBook-Air-2:~ Garry$
```

Sorry for being stupid but how can I fix this??

Thanks

Comment: did u install Django using running setup.py? if so u can remove the django folder and install again

Comment: You should probably stick to pip's builtin (un)install/update methods in the future

Comment: This is why I *always* use virtualenv, so I can't mess up my system python... https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv (There are some warnings on top of the page which you should consider for a nicely working environment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
File "/usr/local/bin/django-admin.py", line 4, in <module>
from pkg_resources import require; require('Django==1.6.dev20130425172216')
```

It looks like the django-admin.py is still the one from version 1.6blabla
I would try to [uninistall everything via pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550226/python-setup-py-uninstall) (1.5 and/or 1.6), make sure `/usr/local/bin/django-admin.py` was also removed, and reinstall 1.5 via pip again.

Comment: I will also suggest him to start learning using virtualenv. Tampering with global site-package is dangerous :) my 2 cent.