# How to uninstall Requests 2.0.0?

Tags: python, python-requests

I installed Requests 2.0.0 library for Python, and I want to uninstall it. Is there some easy way to uninstall it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

If you used pip, you can probably do something like this:

```
pip uninstall requests
```

Otherwise, you'll have to delete the files manually. If you used easy_install, you'll also have to edit easy-install.pth and remove the entry for requests from there.

See also [python setup.py uninstall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550226/python-setup-py-uninstall)

Comment: I tried both and none of them didn't work. If I don't find another way, I will try it manually. Thanks!

Comment: If you run Linux and have installed Requests system-wide, then do not forget `sudo` to succeed. (Consider using virtualenv - helps a lot.)
If you plan to install older version of requests, then `pip install requests=1.9.9` or `pip install requests<2.0.0`.