# How to uninstall packages installed using setuptools

Tags: python, setuptools

That's it, I've some package installed using `setuptools` i.e. I ran the command `python setup.py install` from the package source.

My question is, how do I uninstall the package or upgrade it?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/1550226

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python setup.py uninstall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550226/python-setup-py-uninstall)

Answer (score 2):

Install `pip` using `easy_install`:

```
 easy_install pip
```

and then:

```
pip uninstall <package>
```

PS. Probably [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550226/python-setup-py-uninstall).