# How to run a script when a user uninstalls my package with pip?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, distutils, setup.py

My *setup.py* is adding an entry to the user's crontab on installation.  I want to remove that entry if the user uninstalls the package.  From what I've seen, it seems impossible.  Hoping someone here has a solution.

Comment: There's an open feature request for this on the pip issue tracker: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/857

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible at this moment, see [python setup.py uninstall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550226/python-setup-py-uninstall)

Still, there is this feature request for implementing it https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/857 which is more than 1.5 years old and without any comments on it.

This makes me think that it will not happen too soon. I do also suspect that there may be some other issues that do prevent this from being implemented.