# How to uninstall from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages

Tags: python, macos, pip

how do I uninstall a python modules currently installed in:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

I do not remember how I installed it there but of course pip is not able to find it. I assume it only looks in:

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
```

I'm on a OSX El Capitan (SIP disabled)

Comment: I wouldn't touch that folder.  Use a package manager such as anaconda or homebrew.

Comment: I usually don't touch that folder either but for some reason I have a module installed there and I would like to uninstall it

Comment: Without knowing how it got there, it is difficult to recommend a strategy to remove it.  Perhaps this will help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550226/python-setup-py-uninstall