# How do I deploy a python script that has prerequisites

Tags: python, deployment, wizard

I'm developing an application that requires some initial configuration when first deploying(initial params, server adress,...etc). *This application is written in a different language than python, but I'm using python because it's the language that's the most commonly pre-installed on linux machines.*

I'm thinking of installing the prerequisites at the top of the script like so:

```
import os
os.system("python setup.py install <package>")
from <package> import <stuff>
```

But then I'm installing a package on a computer that belongs to a user, only to use it just once. Should I just uninstall it when my script ends? How do I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not install the python packages from your shell script prior to execution of your program? See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550226/python-setup-py-uninstall) if you're trying to uninstall these packages afterwards. It looks like if you install with `easy_install` or `pip`, you can just use `pip uninstall`.

**Update based on comments:**
You can also consider deploying your script as a separate application using [cx_freeze](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html), [py2exe](http://py2exe.org/), or some other option (see additional info here: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/shipping/freezing/).

Comment: yes, that seems the best solution but still seems kinda dirty. Is it really the best way to go? Also thanks for including the uninstallation method :p

Comment: Another solution is to just ship Python with the prerequisite packages as a stand-alone program. What's better probably depends on the purpose of your program and your end-users.

Comment: If your end-users are all Linux based, consider using freeze or some other packaging: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/shipping/freezing/.

Comment: How do I ship it as a stand-alone program?

Comment: hmmn I could use freeze for linux distribution and py2exe for windows distribution and that would cover everything!

Comment: ah yes yes that's what I'll do! If you post it as an answer then I'll mark it as solved :p

Comment: Edited answer to incorporate comments.