# mac os "command not found" after locally installing a package

Tags: python, macos, macports

I want to install [pysheng](https://github.com/tokland/pysheng) on my computer (macos sierra 10.12). So I download the Zip file and unzip it, the run following code to install it.

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

The package is installed to

```
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
```

Then, I try to run the package but failed.

```
pysheng "http://books.google.com/books?id=m5w5PRj5Nj4C"
```

The error message is

```
-bash: pysheng: command not found.
```

I have macport installed in my computer and there is a line in my `.bash_profile`

```
export PATH="/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH"
```

I don't know if it has something to do with this. So anyone have a clue? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure why you need to mention macports because you didn't install that program using macports

Answer (score 2):

you have to reload bash for it to pick it up.

run `source ~/.bash_profile` or restart your terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You should not put your own modules into the prefix controlled by MacPorts. This is likely to lead to conflicts, as when pysheng was added to MacPorts, files to be installed are already on your system. Do not use `sudo` to install software into `/opt/local`. As setuptools does not have a way to uninstall this, you will have to [clean this up manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550226/python-setup-py-uninstall).

To install your own python modules, either just install them to your `$HOME` and export `PATH` and `PYTHONPATH` in the environment accordingly or create a [virtualenv](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/).