# How to uninstall gym if I installed it by pip install -e '.[all]'?

Tags: openai-gym

I installed gym by `pip install -e '.[all]'`. But I want to uninstall it now, how can I achieve that? I have tried like `pip uninstall gym`, but did not succeed with errors like `Can't uninstall 'gym'. No files were found to uninstall.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem as you.
You have to remove it manually.
See this answer.
[python setup.py uninstall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550226/python-setup-py-uninstall)