# ImportError: cannot import name chirp_connect_set_config

Tags: chirp

I've downloaded ChirpConnect SDK for python (ChirpConnect-Python-3.4.0) and installed it in  RasPi3.
While running the example.py with my key and secret, I'm getting the following error,'**ImportError: cannot import name chirp_connect_set_config**'
What have I done wrong?
Do I need to edit the connect.py file in the chirpsdk?

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the newer version of the SDK has not installed correctly. You can now install the Python SDK directly using PyPi with

```
pip install chirpsdk
```

Now the Chirp Python SDK will be placed under the `chirpsdk` namespace rather than just `chirp`. Then you will just need to edit the `example.py` to import

```
from chirpsdk import ChirpConnect
```

Comment: For a more brute force method, you could explicitly remove any older versions of the Chirp SDK. On macOS this is something like - sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/chirp*

Comment: See the following post for more info on this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550226/python-setup-py-uninstall