# Compiling Python 3 extension module on Mac

Tags: python, c, macos, gcc, compiler-errors

I'm trying to write a [Python extension module](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html) in C. I'm running macOS Catalina and have a Homebrew installation of Python 3 (with default installation settings). When I try to compile the following file:

```
#include <Python/Python.h>

static PyObject* world(PyObject* self, PyObject* args)
{
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    Py_RETURN_NONE;
}

static PyMethodDef methods[] = {
    {"world", world, METH_VARARGS, "Prints \"Hello world!\""},
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};

static struct PyModuleDef module = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    "name for the module",
    "docstring for the module",
    -1,
    methods
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_hello(void)
{
    return PyModule_Create(&module);
}
```

by running `gcc hello.c` in my terminal, I get the following messages:

```
hello.c:15:5: error: use of undeclared identifier
      'PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT'
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    ^
hello.c:14:27: error: variable has incomplete type
      'struct PyModuleDef'
static struct PyModuleDef module = {
                          ^
hello.c:14:15: note: forward declaration of 'struct PyModuleDef'
static struct PyModuleDef module = {
              ^
hello.c:24:12: warning: implicit declaration of function
      'PyModule_Create' is invalid in C99
      [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    return PyModule_Create(&module);
           ^
1 warning and 2 errors generated.
```

Is there a way to fix this? I've tried playing around with the `-L` and `-I` flags to no avail. I think this might be happening because it’s using the header for Python 2 rather than Python 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use distutils

create setup.py. e.g.

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

def main():
    setup(name="hello",
            version="1.0.0",
            description="desc",
            author="<your name>",
            author_email="a@b.com",
            ext_modules=[Extension("hello",["hello.c"])])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

in c file change include to:

```
#include <Python.h>
```

Assuming your c file name is hello.c and setup.py is placed in the same directory:

```
python3 setup.py install
```

In your case, verify whether it is "python3" or "python".
This should build your module and install it, you should be able to see the compiler and linker commands

Comment: Thanks, I’ll try this when I have the chance. Is this approach new for Python 3? For Python 2, I could just gcc my C file to a .so file and, in the same directory, import the module.

Comment: You still can use gcc but distutils is a standard way of building and distributing modules. It invokes the gcc with the correct flags and link relevant libraries. Distutils has been there since python 1.6

Comment: Do you know why this creates two folders under the created `build` directory? (For me it's `lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7` which contains `hello.cpython-37m-darwin.so` and `temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.7` which contains `hello.o`.)

Comment: The temp directory holds the object files. Think of it as a temporary work area used by distutil to build the python module. The other one contains the final python module: https://docs.python.org/2.0/inst/how-build-works.html

Comment: It seems I can access the module even from a different directory. Is it being installed globally? If so, how can I keep it local for testing purposes, or uninstall it?

Comment: instead of 'install' use 'build' flag. That will just build the module and not install it in site-package. To uninstall you will have to record the path where it installed the module into. That will be "python setup.py install --record files.txt". Then delete the files that are listed in files.txt. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550226/python-setup-py-uninstall

Comment: I don't know if you're familiar with the Numpy C API, but do you by any chance know why I'm getting the warning *"Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with #define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION"*, even though Homebrew says my numpy is up-to-date (1.17.4)? I'm following the example here: https://scipy-lectures.org/advanced/interfacing_with_c/interfacing_with_c.html#id1

Comment: Never used it. But the doc says you can ignore it. Visit this link and search for numpy http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html#warnings