# How to uninstall specific python program from the Terminal?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

I wanted to have videos watchable via terminal, so I followed [this tutorial](https://www.hecticgeek.com/yt-youtube-browser-ubuntu-linux/). After installing, it did not work out, and I had to uninstall. The program is referred to as Whitey with the input being "yt".

I want to get rid of the command from the terminal as to not cause future conflicts. How can I do that?

Comment: Depending on what you have done and your setup, it might be as easy as `pip uninstall whitey`

Answer (score 0):

Helo Axl

Did you install Whitey via pip install?
If so just try to run

pip uninstall whitey

Comment: I ran the installation via python setup.py install

Comment: Hello Axl, then I think that you have to clean it up kinds of manually. You can follow the easy instructions here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1550235/2171270