# setuptools giving `TypeError` for minimal setup.py example

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools

I'm trying to troubleshoot an issue I've been having with `setuptools`. Even with this minimal setup.py example, I get the following error:

**setup.py**

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(
    name="packagename"
)
```

Running `python setup.py`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 2, in <module>
    setup(
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 86, in setup
    _install_setup_requires(attrs)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 75, in _install_setup_requires
    dist = MinimalDistribution(attrs)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 57, in __init__
    super().__init__(filtered)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 474, in __init__
    for ep in metadata.entry_points(group='distutils.setup_keywords'):
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_vendor/importlib_metadata/__init__.py", line 999, in entry_points
    return SelectableGroups.load(eps).select(**params)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_vendor/importlib_metadata/__init__.py", line 449, in load
    ordered = sorted(eps, key=by_group)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_vendor/importlib_metadata/__init__.py", line 996, in <genexpr>
    eps = itertools.chain.from_iterable(
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_vendor/importlib_metadata/_itertools.py", line 16, in unique_everseen
    k = key(element)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_vendor/importlib_metadata/__init__.py", line 931, in _normalized_name
    return self._name_from_stem(stem) or super()._normalized_name
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_vendor/importlib_metadata/__init__.py", line 600, in _normalized_name
    return Prepared.normalize(self.name)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_vendor/importlib_metadata/__init__.py", line 855, in normalize
    return re.sub(r"[-_.]+", "-", name).lower().replace('-', '_')
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/re.py", line 210, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

I'm using Python 3.8.13 and setuptools 65.4.1. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling setuptools with pip.

Comment: I cannot run `python setup.py` on `python3.8` with setuptools version `65.4.1`, I have to pass it a command. Running `python setup.py build` I don't get an error. Are you sure this is the exact command you are running?

Comment: All of `python setup.py`, `python setup.py --help` and `python setup.py build` throw the same error for me.

Comment: Even if I set `name=4`, I can't get that error to manifest. I don't have to `pip install setuptools`. Maybe try to create and activate a new conda environment `conda create -n testenv python=3.8 -y && conda activate testenv` just to be sure you get a clean build

Comment: Yes, things work as expected with a clean build. I suppose I need to investigate what could be causing a conflict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue ended up being an improperly uninstalled package. See, for example, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1550235/2870171) detailing how to remove a package installed with `python setup.py install`. Neglecting to delete the containing directory results in the error described here.