# Can no longer install Stable-baselines after trying to install Atari roms

Tags: python, installation, pip, stable-baselines

Yesterday, I installed stable-baselines 3 on Windows 10 by typing the following in the Command Prompt

```
py -m pip install stable-baselines3[extra]
```

It installed and I ran it in Python with no issues. Today, I tried downloading some Atari roms to work on a Breakout reinforcement learning project, and suddenly nothing worked (I couldn't even import stable-baselines anymore, due to some strange error about missing DLL files, which I now see [is an issue](https://stable-baselines3.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/install.html)). I decided to uninstall everything (stable baselines, gym, atari_py) using

```
py -m pip uninstall
```

and specifying the related packages, the reinstall from from scratch. But now I'm unable to even install stable baselines. Using the command from before, I'm currently getting the follwing error:

[image: command prompt error]

I've tried following all the recommendations about updating pip, steuptools, wheel, ez_setup, etc. that I could find, but nothing has worked. Since it worked yesterday, I suppose that maybe there are rogue files somewhere inhiniting the installation.

Upon further investigation, it seems that using pip uninstall may have been [a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550226/python-setup-py-uninstall), at which point I looked for any program files and folders related to gym, stable-baselines, and atari, and deleted them, but still no luck. I'm a bit out of my depth here. Does anyone have any recommendations?

Comment: In general, the best practice is to set up `Virtual Environments (venvs)`, for each codebase.