# pkg_resources.VersionConflict when I try to start paster serve

Tags: python, pylons

Im trying to use port 80.
So when i use the command "sudo paster serve development.ini --reload"

I get this error

pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (Pylons 0.9.7 (/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6), Requirement.parse('Pylons>=1.0'))

I tried to do "easy_install pylons"

but I get

"Pylons 1.0 is already the active version in easy-install.pth"

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like Python is finding Pylons 0.9.7 before 1.0 in the module search path.

If that's the case, the simplest solution is probably to use your package manager to uninstall Pylons 0.9.7 and then use easy_install to restore anything that got removed as a side-effect.

If that doesn't do it, try also [removing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231688/how-do-i-remove-packages-installed-with-pythons-easy-install) Pylons 1.0 and re-running easy_install... though I prefer using [virtualenv](http://www.arthurkoziel.com/2008/10/22/working-virtualenv/) to keep my system packages cleanly separated from the stuff installed by easy_install.

As an alternative, you could create a clean virtual environment with `virtualenv --no-site-packages whatever` and then easy_install Pylons 1.0 into that.

Comment: If you have a bad version in your global site-packages (`/usr/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages`) you might also want to just delete that version.