# Problem upgrading a tool using easy_install

Tags: python, easy-install

On Ubuntu server :

```
# easy_install mercurial
Searching for mercurial
Best match: mercurial 1.8.1
Adding mercurial 1.8.1 to easy-install.pth file

Using /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages
Processing dependencies for mercurial
Finished processing dependencies for mercurial
```

Now, if I do `hg version` it says I'm using the 1.6.3 version!

I want to use the last version. the -U option don't work. The -m option don't work.

Any idea what's the problem?

Comment: user/local/bin/hg  Not sure if it's a version I installed with easy_install or manually, I'm still a bit lost with those things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem by uninstalling the package following this :

[How do I remove packages installed with Python's easy_install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231688/how-do-i-remove-packages-installed-with-pythons-easy-install)

then reinstalling.

Now, easy_install don't install the very last version I wanted, so I'll install it manually certainly.

Comment: Take a look at `pip` as Sridhar pointed out. I've found it usually brings you closer to the edge releases. Caution needed as usual.

Answer (score 0):

You can install mercurial using aptitude. I'm not sure why installing mercurial with easy_install would install the mercurial binaries for you. easy_install is for python packages.

Try this:

```
sudo aptitude update
sudo aptitude reinstall mercurial
hg --version
```

Should display 1.8 now

Comment: I know that, but it will not install the 1.8.1 version, nor the 1.8.

Comment: By the way, your solution does install a parallel version of hg that is under the other one, so I even don't have access to it until I uninstall the easy_install one.

Comment: That will happen when easy_install puts the binary earlier in your path than the aptitude packages are located at. As you noted yourself removing the easy_install binaries should mostly fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try this:

```
sudo easy_install pip
sudo pip install -U mercurial
```