# Setup.py for uninstalling via pip

Tags: python, uninstallation, pip

According to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231688/how-do-i-remove-packages-installed-with-pythons-easy-install), pip offers a facility for uninstalling eggs, which it's help also indicates.

I have a project that, once installed, has a structure in my local site-packages folder that looks like this:

```
projecta/
projecta-1.0-py2.6.egg-info/
```

Using an up to date version, `pip uninstall projecta` asks me the following question:

```
  /path/to/python2.6/site-packages/projecta-1.0-py2.6.egg-info
Proceed (y/n)?
```

Answering `y` will remove the `.egg-info` directory, but not the main `projecta` directory, without saying there was any sort of error. Why doesn't pip manage or know to remove this directory?

The project itself is installed via a `setup.py` file using distutils. Are there any special settings I could/should use in that file to help pip with the removal process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I recall correctly `pip` knows how to uninstall packages installed via `setuptools/distribute`, not raw `distutils`.

There are some `setuptools`'s features pip is based on - like `--record` option, which stores package metadata (and it is what allows pip to uninstal package related files).

Try doing:

```
$ pip install /path/to/projecta
$ pip uninstall projecta
```