# Removing cocos2d-python from Mac

Tags: python, cocos2d-python

I installed cocos2d today on OS X Lion, but whenever I try to import **cocos** in the Python interpreter, I get a bunch of import errors.

> File "", line 1, in     File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/ 
>   python2.7/site-packages/cocos2d-0.5.0-py2.7.egg/cocos/**init**.py", 
>   line 105, in  
>       import_all()    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/ 
>   python2.7/site-packages/cocos2d-0.5.0-py2.7.egg/cocos/**init**.py", 
>   line 89, in import_all 
>       import actions    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/ 
>   python2.7/site-packages/cocos2d-0.5.0-py2.7.egg/cocos/actions/ 
>   **init**.py", line 37, in  
>       from basegrid_actions import *    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/ 
>   python2.7/site-packages/cocos2d-0.5.0-py2.7.egg/cocos/actions/ 
>   basegrid_actions.py", line 62, in  
>       from pyglet.gl import *    File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/pyglet/gl/**init**.py", line  510,
>   in     File
>   "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/pyglet/window/**init**.py",  line
>   1669, in     File
>   "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/pyglet/window/carbon/ 
>   **init**.py", line 69, in     File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/pyglet/lib.py", line 90, in 
>   load_library    File
>   "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/pyglet/lib.py", line 226, in 
>   load_framework    File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/ 
>   python2.7/ctypes/**init**.py", line 431, in LoadLibrary 
>       return self._dlltype(name)    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/ 
>   python2.7/ctypes/**init**.py", line 353, in **init** 
>       self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)  OSError: dlopen(/System/Library/Frameworks/QuickTime.framework/  QuickTime, 6):
>   no suitable image found.  Did find: 
>           /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickTime.framework/QuickTime: mach-o, but  wrong architecture 
>           /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickTime.framework/QuickTime: mach-o, but  wrong architecture

Since I can't fix it, I'd like to remove cocos2d entirely. The problem is that I can't seem to find a guide anywhere that details how to remove it from the Python installation.

Any help regarding either of these problems is greatly appreciated.

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231688/how-do-i-remove-packages-installed-with-pythons-easy-install

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could fix it.
The problem comes from the fact that cocos2D is built on top of Pyglet, and the stable release of pyglet does not yet support Mac OS X 64 bits architecture. You have to use the 1.2 release of pyglet or later, which by now is not released yet.

A workaround is to remove any existing Pyglet install:

pip uninstall piglet

Then install the latest Pyglet from the mercurial repository

pip install hg+https://pyglet.googlecode.com/hg/