# api = twitter.Api() AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Api

Tags: python, api, twitter, archlinux

I have been trying to write a simple mention grabber to get started with the twitter Api. Howsoever I've been experienceing some difficulties when initializing the Api.
Running python2 on archlinux I installed twitter via easy_install, built it from source and installed it via pip. None of this seems to be working.

```
zergling :: ~/dev/kritter » python2
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jan 31 2012, 13:26:35) 
[GCC 4.6.2 20120120 (prerelease)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import twitter
>>> api = twitter.Api()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Api'
```

Howsoever the pydoc for twitter is there. I have no clue what I'm doing wrong. I hope you can help

**UPDATE:** 
I tried using `twitter.api()` instead of `twitter.Api()` and got the following error:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "main.py", line 8, in 
    api = twitter.api()
    TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Additional Informations:

```
>>> print dir(twitter)
['NoAuth', 'OAuth', 'Twitter', 'TwitterError', 'TwitterHTTPError', 'TwitterResponse',  'TwitterStream', 'UserPassAuth', '__all__', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__',  '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', 'api', 'auth', 'oauth', 'read_token_file', 'stream', 'twitter_globals', 'write_token_file']
>>> print twitter.__path__
['/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twitter-1.7.2-py2.7.egg/twitter']
```

Comment: try to "print dir(twitter)" and "print twitter.__path__", can see what's the methods available from the module, and where it's located (to be sure you're using the right one.)

Comment: @tito: got the following out of this. using twitter.api() i get another error beeing: `api = twitter.api(); TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`

Comment: Well, you see that their is no Api or api class/func in the dir()

Comment: I'm sure you're not looking the right documentation for that module. There is many twitter python wrapper, and look like this one is different :)

Comment: The twitter-1.7.2 is not the same as http://code.google.com/p/python-twitter, so don't look over that doc, it's a different project

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think you've installed one twitter package, and look at another documentation. Ie: python-1.7.2 is the project from https://github.com/sixohsix/twitter, while you're looking at the http://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/ documentation. No match between both :)

So for the one you've installed, if you check the source code, a [stream example](https://github.com/sixohsix/twitter/blob/master/twitter/stream_example.py) is available, and other various examples in the pydoc:

```
  from twitter import Twitter
  # ...
  twitter = Twitter(
      auth=OAuth(token, token_key, con_secret, con_secret_key)))

  # Get the public timeline
  twitter.statuses.public_timeline()
```

Comment: thank you, this totally helped. i just thought easy_install would make my live easy.

Comment: To understand what happened, if you are using [ipython](http://ipython.org/), you can print the object "twitter" and see where it comes from. If it's an .egg file and it's python_twitter, you might have to follow the easy steps described here (it worked for me, I had installed python_twitter using easy_install):
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231688/how-do-i-remove-packages-installed-with-pythons-easy-install

Comment: I had installed with `pip install twitter`, when it should've been `pip install python-twitter`

Comment: this suggests he use another API.  You should answer his question and not propose another product.  The correct answer is by "ayu for u" below.

Comment: what is `OAuth` now

Answer (score 16):

i found solution to this problem in following site

[http://himanen.info/solved-attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-api/][1]

There are two Python libraries conflicting: twitter library and python-twitter library. The solution was quite straightforward:

```
pip uninstall twitter
```

Then I just made it sure that python-twitter was certainly installed:

```
pip install python-twitter
```

Thank you himanen it worked for me

Comment: Thank you, this was it.

Answer (score 15):

I got the same error because my python file was called twitter.py. It contained:

```
import twitter
api = twitter.Api (consumer_key=...
```

I renamed the file to twitterdata.py, removed twitter.pyc and then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

probably check [twython](https://github.com/kracekumar/Twython), I have made all neccessary Ouath implementation using [requests](http://www.python-requests.org).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the python-twitter wrapper. during installation process it must have created an eggfile with the name twitter.py.egg rename it by some other name like help.py.egg it will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Use module **python-twitter** instead of **twitter**

```
$ pip install python-twitter
```

*Reference : https://python-twitter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html*

*For Modules Documentation : https://python-twitter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/twitter.html#modules-documentation*

Answer (score 0):

i found solution to this problem in following site

[http://himanen.info/solved-attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-api/][1]

There are two Python libraries conflicting: twitter library and python-twitter library. The solution was quite straightforward:

pip uninstall twitter
Then I just made it sure that python-twitter was certainly installed:

pip install python-twitter
thank you himanen..it really works

Comment: The link you shared is broken: "The page you requested could not be found"