# How to uninstall inactive version of packages installed using easy_install

Tags: python, package, pip, easy-install

I found out that I have two versions of `pip` installed on my OS X, and I would like to remove the older version (which is also labelled as 'inactive' by `yolk -l`).

In another [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231688/how-do-i-remove-packages-installed-with-pythons-easy-install) post, I found that you can uninstall a package using `pip uninstall` command. But in my case, I would like to remove only the older version of the package, leaving the active version untouched. How should I do this properly?

Comment: It's suprising `pip list` or `pip freeze` doesn't list in-active versions as `yolk -l` does. And that there isn't command to clear system of in-active versions. Have you found some (pre-automated) way (other than self-scripting it, as suggested by Pooria below)?

Answer (score 0):

to remove your inactive version, you should delete it from easy-install.pth file, and remove egg directory of that package.
I don't have OS X, but in my ubuntu, easy-install.pth is located in "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/easy-install.pth" and egg directories are in "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/".