# System-level vs application-level package distribution

Tags: rubygems, package, packaging, easy-install, software-distribution

If I create a FOSS command-line utility (i.e. an *application* rather than a *library*) and I want to distribute it as a package for convenient installation, **is it better practice to do this via**:

- [application-level package management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_software_package_management_systems#Application-level_package_managers) (e.g. RubyGems, if it's written in Ruby; EasyInstall if Python, etc), or
- [systems-level package management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_management_system#Application-level_package_managers) (e.g. MacPorts for the Mac, Debian Packages for Debian, etc).

*NB. If you believe there is no generally correct practice but rather that there are particular circumstances under which one or the other approach is clearly best, then what are these circumstances?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that the procedure followed in the case of applications whose users are happy with the way they're distributed, is roughly as follows:

[image]

Take, for example:

- **Bundler**: written in Ruby and useful to Ruby developers; distributed via application-level package.
- **fwknop**: written in Perl (originally, at least) and useful to end-users; distributed via systems-level packages/installers.
- **Pandoc**: written in Haskell and may be useful to Haskell developers in the course of developing Haskell applications, but *also* useful to others; distributed *both* [via application-level and via systems-level packages](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/installing.html).

There are probably better examples than these. Also, my conclusions so far are just observational ones: I haven't found a reference laying out this decision flow explicitly. As such, I'd welcome a more comprehensive answer.

*NB. The code for the flowchart is [online](https://gist.github.com/3015915#file_packaging_flowchart.tex), in case you'd like to adapt it for your answer. To be able to use it, you'll need a working LaTeX installation.*

Answer (score 1):

According to [this blog entry](http://workaround.org/easy-install-debian), the main reasons you should

> **NEVER** install a Python module system-wide with setuptools/ez_setup on your Debian system

are

1. that you can have different versions of the same Python modules in different installation paths (installed via `easy_install` and `aptitude`)
2. there is no `easy_uninstall`. (However, `pip` seems to be able to do this: [How do I remove packages installed with Python's easy_install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231688/how-do-i-remove-packages-installed-with-pythons-easy-install))

The same applies to a CLI tool, which also is a (Python) module of sorts.

Of course, packaging for `easy_install` requires less work than packaging for all the system package managers out there. But why don't you package your tool with `easy_install` and ask somebody who is familiar with packaging for the particular targets for help? (For Debian, you can try sending an e-mail to `submit@bugs.debian.org` with a subject that starts with "[needs-packaging]".)

Let me tell only from my limited experience as user -- Python and Debian/Ubuntu. When I finally switched from Windows to Ubuntu, one of the main reasons was the painless installation of almost all software *that has been packaged for Debian*. One of the questions during the first period of transition were:

"What's the most recent multi-way diff tool? OK, there's meld and diffuse. Let's see..."

```
sudo apt-get install meld diffuse
```

"OK. And this clipboard manager was called Parcellite?"

```
sudo apt-get install parcellite
```

"I love Task Coach. Do they have it?"

```
sudo apt-get install taskcoach
```

"Now why is `svn` not installed out of the box?"

```
sudo apt-get install svn
... (some error)
apt-file search svn
... (tl;dr)
apt-file search svn | grep /svn$
sudo apt-get install subversion
```

So much for the convenience of packaging. Note that at least the first two tools mentioned are pure Python tools, but *I don't care* -- the **system package manager** does everything for me. Perhaps I would have even installed them using `easy_install` if that was the only option, but then I could have been made aware of the risks of systemwide installations using `easy_install`, and would have dropped it.

Comment: I'm grateful for your answer, but it seems to be a bit one-sided and to be based on just one source, which makes at least one criticism that isn't really valid anymore.

Comment: @sampablokuper: The issue with different versions in different paths still applies.

Comment: Even so, I'm concerned not to attribute a particular application-level package manager's shortcomings to application-level package managers in general. I think it's only if they (nearly) all share the shortcomings that the shortcomings are relevant to my question.