# Just installed BeautifulSoup Python 3.3.0

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Does anyone know how to fix it.
I am using Mac OS 10.8.2

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/bs4/__init__.py", line 359
    print soup.prettify()
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: try running the import statement from the terminal, what do you get?

Comment: How did you install bs4? Given that you apparently don't know what `pip` is, I'm wondering if you got it in some incorrect way…

Comment: I installed it and can confirm that this problem does not exist in the latest version of BeautifulSoup, so you have by mistake installed an old Python 2 only version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Python 3 `print` is a function; it should be:

```
print(soup.prettify())
```

Install `bs4` correctly or use a newer version if it is a bug.  `beautifulsoup4==4.1.3` works fine on Python 3.3.

Comment: I am surprised BeautifulSoup has this problem when it officially supports Python 3.x. Seems like monkey patch bs4 is the only way to go

Comment: Thanks, I am using 4.1.3. It should be a bug

Comment: @IanZhaoqiLeng: I've looked at installed 4.1.3 source in site-packages; it uses `()` correctly. I've installed it using `pip install beautifulsoup4`.

Comment: I used  "pip install beautifulsoup4"  But it shows "-bash: pip: command not found"

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian: Anyway, I switch to python 2.7, and everything just works. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You probably want `pip-3.3`, not `pip` (because the latter would install for 2.7). You may not have it yet, in which case you have to `easy_install-3.3 pip`. You may not even have `easy_install` yet for 3.3, in which case you have to manually download and install `distribute`. (For the stock Mac 2.7, you definitely have `easy_install` but not `pip`. Installing `pip` should be the first thing you do.)

Comment: @abarnert: you should probably address your comment to Ian. I only use `pip` to install inside virtualenv. I should've mentioned it. Each virtualenv automatically installs distribute (easy_install), pip. It is the simplest way to install them. You shouldn't use easy_install unless it is necessary (if pip can't install a package) because there is [no uninstall](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1231688/4279) so you can't remove, update packages installed with easy_install properly. Also a rule of thumb: if you need `sudo` before pip than use system package manager instead to avoid breaking stuff.

Comment: My comment was addressed to Ian (comments on SO without a target always notify the OP), in particular his comment "-bash: pip: command not found". One of the cases where you need to use easy_install is to get pip itself, and that's the only thing I was recommending it for. Also, your rule of thumb only applies to linux; there *is* no package manager that can install stuff for the stock OS X Python, or for the python.org installer versions, so `sudo pip` (or `sudo pip-X.Y`) is the standard way to do things.

Comment: @abarnert: comments on my *answer* without a target notify me, not the OP ([see p.1](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/137096)). There are package managers on OS X e.g., homebrew.

Comment: There are third-party add-on package managers, but there is no system package manager, and all of the add-on managers explicitly avoid touching system software. In particular, they will not install modules for the system Python, or for python.org GUI-installer versions. On top of that, Homebrew deliberately does not include Python (or Ruby or Perl) modules at all, explicitly recommending that you use pip for that. So your rule of thumb is still completely wrong on OS X.

Comment: @abarnert: does `brew`-installed `pip` command requires `sudo`?

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/il-vladislav/BeautifulSoup4 Just copy this to Lib directory. It is fixed version for Python 3.3

Answer (score 0):

Beautiful Soup 4 works on both Python 2 (2.6+) and Python 3.

Beautiful Soup is licensed under the MIT license, so you can also download the tarball, drop the bs4/ directory into almost any Python application (or into your library path) and start using it immediately. If you want to do this under Python 3, you will need to manually convert the code using 2to3.

http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

use 
python ../python33/Tools/Script/2to3.py -w beautifulsoup4-4.3.2 
is be ok