# BeautifulSoup4 on Python 3.3.2 issue

Tags: python

I'm having this issue on `BeautifulSoup4` on `Python 3.3.2` on `MAC OSX 10.8`:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/bs4/__init__.py", line 359
    print soup.prettify()
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13096959/just-installed-beautifulsoup-python-3-3-0/17543764#17543764) old post, claiming the issue would be fixed with Python 3.3, maybe this is a regression?

Comment: Maybe you installed it incorrectly. How did you install it?

Comment: I tried easy_install, pip and setup.py, no luck. Running on Python 2.7.2 works though...