# How to Install BeautifulSoup4 Python 3.3 Mac

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, python-3.x

Is there a way to install beautifulsoup4 for python 3.3? `pip install beautifulsoup4`, `easy_install beautifulsoup4`, and `python setup.py install` for beautifulsoup all only install it for python 2.7. When I go to /Library/Python there is no 3.3 folder, only 2.3, 2.5, 2.6, and 2.7. Is there a way to get this to work? Does python 3.3 not have a site-packages folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You may want to read the last answer on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13096959/just-installed-beautifulsoup-python-3-3-0), also, be sure you are using pip for 3.3, not for 2.X. Hope it helps.