# BeautifulSoup4 throwing an error in Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

i am trying to create a webpage scraper and I want to use BeautifulSoup to do so. I installed BeautifulSoup 4.3.2 as the website said it was compatible with python 3.x. I used

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

to install it. But when i run

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = input("Enter a URL (start with www): ")

link = "http://" + url

data = requests.get(link).content

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

for link in soup.find_all('a'):

   print(link.get('href'))
```

i get an error that says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/user/Desktop/project.py", line 1, in <module>
  from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.1/lib/python3.1/site-packages   /bs4/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
from .builder import builder_registry, ParserRejectedMarkup
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.1/lib/python3.1/site-packages/bs4/builder /__init__.py", line 308, in <module>
from .. import _htmlparser
  ImportError: cannot import name _htmlparser
```

Comment: Can you please try changing `data = link.text` to `data = requests.get(link).content` instead and try rerunning the code? The way I see it, you just straight up went to `link.text` without even invoking `Requests` to get the content of the URL.

Comment: I made the changes you stated above but still wouldn't get past the import error of BeautifulSoup. I understand it works in python 2.7 but im required to use python 3 and im not understanding why its not importing properly.

Comment: See [this](http://bugs.python.org/issue14538) for a related discussion on this bug. Have you tried on the *latest* Python 3.x release? I use 2.7, where this issue is non-existent so I can't really comment. Will check with Python 3.x though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just installed Python 3.x on my end and tested the latest download of BS4. Didn't work. However, a fix can be found here: https://github.com/il-vladislav/BeautifulSoup4 (credits to GitHub user Il Vladislav, whoever you are).

Download the zip, overwrite the `bs4` folder inside your `BeautifulSoup` download, then reinstall it via `python setup.py install`. Works now on my end, as you can see in the screenshot below where an error is evident before working completely.

**Code:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = input("Enter a URL (start with www): ")
link = "http://" + url
data = requests.get(link).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

for link in soup.find_all('a'):
   print(link.get('href'))
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Relevant SO topic found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13096959/just-installed-beautifulsoup-python-3-3-0), showing that BS4 is not *totally* compatible with Python 3.x yet (even after 2 years).

Comment: I appreciate your help so much!! Im just not seeing the zip file you've mentioned. I see bs4,.gitattributes and .gitignore is it one of those? If you dont mind pointing me in the right direction i would appreciate it very much! Edit: Nevermind i found it :)

Comment: On the lower right side of that exact link there's a `Download ZIP` option. Should give you a `BeautifulSoup4-master` ZIP file. Extract it, go inside, and look for the `bs4` folder. Copy it and overwrite the `bs4` folder inside your original `BeautifulSoup4` download. Then reinstall `BeautifulSoup` via the command line.

Comment: Thank you! I got rid of the BS4 error. Now ive just gotta install requests i suppose because it says no module requests exists. I thought i installed it with pip though.

Comment: `pip` is one of the easier ways to install stuff, but it's not foolproof. Unless my installations require a load of dependencies (I'm looking at *you*, `matplotlib`), I install the good ol'-fashioned way. Also, yes, reinstall `Requests`. Make sure the correct version for `Python 3.x` is installed. :) Good luck!

Comment: And it works! I cant thank you enough! I really appreciate it. Have a good day! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think there might be an error in the source file, specifically here:

```
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.1/lib/python3.1/site-packages/bs4/builder /__init__.py", line 308, in <module>
  from .. import _htmlparser
```

In my installation, line 308 of `bs4/builder /__init__.py`

```
  from . import _htmlparser
```

You could probably just fix it there and see if bs4 will successfully import.  Not sure which version of bs4 you got installed, but mine is at 4.3.2, and the `_htmlparser.py` is also at `bs4/builder`

Answer (score 0):

I just edited the `bs4/builder/_htmlparser.py` so that

A) HTMLParseError wasn't imported

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser
```

B) The HTMLParseError class was defined

```
class HTMLParseError(Exception):
    """Exception raised for all parse errors."""

    def __init__(self, msg, position=(None, None)):
        assert msg
        self.msg = msg
        self.lineno = position[0]
        self.offset = position[1]

    def __str__(self):
        result = self.msg
        if self.lineno is not None:
            result = result + ", at line %d" % self.lineno
        if self.offset is not None:
            result = result + ", column %d" % (self.offset + 1)
        return result
```

This probably isn't the best since HTMLParserError isn't going to be raised. But! Your exception will just be uncaught and is unhandled anyways.