# ImportError: cannot import name 'HTMLAwareEntitySubstitution'

Tags: beautifulsoup, python-3.5

I just setup beautifulsoup4-4.1.0 and upgrade pip to version 9.0.1.
When I write this :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

error occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    from .builder import builder_registry, ParserRejectedMarkup
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\bs4\builder\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from bs4.element import (
ImportError: cannot import name 'HTMLAwareEntitySubstitution'
```

what should I do?Many thanks.

Comment: sorry, I must correct my description above.My beautifulsoup's version is 4.5.1.

Comment: Did you use pip to install bs4?

Comment: yes.Actually I used pip8 to install bs4.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the version you have it appears that there [might be an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22182634/beautifulsoup4-throwing-an-error-in-python-3-x) in `bs4/builder/__init__.py`.

This line, `from .. import _htmlparser` should be:  `from . import _htmlparser`

However, I would suggest re-installing the package using current version of `pip` before you go off the beaten path and try editing the source code.

To re-install: `pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall beautifulsoup4`