# Python Openopt Integration Prob (IP) interalg TypeError 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, optimization, ip, nlp

I am trying to run the program found here:
[FuncDesigner integration example 3](http://trac.openopt.org/openopt/browser/PythonPackages/FuncDesigner/FuncDesigner/examples/integrate3.py?rev=1214)
However i get the error/output:

```
------------------------- OpenOpt 0.34 -------------------------
solver: interalg_0.21   problem: unnamed    type: IP
 iter   objFunVal   
    0  0.000e+00 
OpenOpt Warning: solver interalg_0.21 require p.fTol value (required objective function     tolerance); 10^-7 will be used
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/morten/Desktop/integrate3.py", line 27, in <module>
r = p.solve('interalg', maxIter = 50000, maxActiveNodes = 150, maxNodes = 500000,     iprint = 100)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openopt/kernel/baseProblem.py", line 235, in solve
    return runProbSolver(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openopt/kernel/runProbSolver.py", line 237, in runProbSolver
solver(p)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openopt/solvers/UkrOpt/interalg_oo.py", line 226, in __solver__
ip = func10(y, e, vv)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openopt/solvers/UkrOpt/interalgMisc.py", line 42, in func10
domain = ooPoint(domain, skipArrayCast = True)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I have searched and found i wrongfully call a module instead of a class if i am not mistaken, but i can't find my error.

(In the end what i would like to do is minimize over an integration using FuncDesigner, but right now i am stuck at the integration part.)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found my error.**

I didn't have the latest version of openopt, funcdesigner etc.

I uninstalled Openopt - first from the software center and then using pip to uninstall openopt, funcdesigner, DerApproximator and SpaceFuncs. (easy_install pip and run the commands:"sudo pip uninstall SpaceFuncs" etc. [pip installation and use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231688/how-do-i-remove-packages-installed-with-pythons-easy-install))

I then reinstalled everything with easyinstall and now it works.