# Unable to uninstall package installed by easy_install

Tags: python, ubuntu, easy-install

I installed module beaver by using the following command

```
easy_install Beaver
```

Now I need to remove this package from my server and I do the following:

```
easy_install -m Beaver
```

But the package is still in the system and I get the following message:

```
Searching for Beaver
Best match: Beaver 30

Using /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

Because this distribution was installed --multi-version, before you can
import modules from this package in an application, you will need to
'import pkg_resources' and then use a 'require()' call similar to one of
these examples, in order to select the desired version:

    pkg_resources.require("Beaver")  # latest installed version
    pkg_resources.require("Beaver==30")  # this exact version
    pkg_resources.require("Beaver>=30")  # this version or higher

Processing dependencies for Beaver
Finished processing dependencies for Beaver
```

The following command:

```
which beaver
```

shows me path to this module

```
/usr/local/bin/beaver
```

Help me to remove this package from system completly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a good answer about it: [How do I remove packages installed with Python's easy_install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231688/how-do-i-remove-packages-installed-with-pythons-easy-install)

I think it is easier to install pip and uninstall this package. Like the link above says, you can remove the package directory that can be easily found in your site-packages Python directory (but I really prefer the first option).

```
pip uninstall Beaver
```