# ImportError: cannot import name argparser

Tags: python, python-2.7, youtube

I have installed Google APIs Client Library for Python via `easy_install.py --upgrade google-api-python-client`. When I run a script that contains `from oauth2client.tools import argparser, run_flow` returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\name\Desktop\file.py", line 9, in <module>
from oauth2client.tools import argparser, run_flow
ImportError: cannot import name argparser
```

I am using python 2.7.6 64x in win 8. The strange thing is that doing the same procedure in another pc in win 7 it working perfect. What is going wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: What does `import oauth2client.tools; print oauth2client.tools.__file__` produce? does it match your expectation of where `oauth2client` is installed?

Comment: Returns `C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\google_api_python_client-1.1-py2.7.egg\oauth2client\tools.pyc` Is that ok? I think it is.

Comment: That's an older version, the latest version is 1.2. `argparser` was added in 1.2.

Comment: What was the output of `easy_install.py --upgrade google-api-python-client`?

Comment: I thought that I have done it five minutes ago but it didn't work. Any way I did it again and worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `argparser` object was [added on 29 March 2013](https://github.com/google/oauth2client/commit/79daca0a32c7eba4867692f650411d099025501d), *after* [`google-api-python-client` version 1.1](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/google-api-python-client/1.1) was released.

It appears your `easy_install.py --upgrade google-api-python-client` call failed to upgrade your local installation, you are still trying to import from version 1.1. The output of `import oauth2client.tools; print oauth2client.tools.__file__` shows this:

```
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\google_api_python_client-1.1-py2.7.egg\oauth2clie‌​nt\tools.pyc
```

You can see the version number in the egg path.

Comment: It is strange I am facing the same problem again. I upgrate via `easy_install.py --upgrade google-api-python-client` and returned `Searching for google-api-python-client
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/google-api-python-client/
Reading http://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/
Best match: google-api-python-client 1.2
Processing google_api_python_client-1.2-py2.7.egg
google-api-python-client 1.2 is already the active version in easy-install.pth`

Comment: `Using c:\python27\lib\site-packages\google_api_python_client-1.2-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for google-api-python-client
Finished processing dependencies for google-api-python-client`

Comment: However, when running `import oauth2client.tools; print oauth2client.tools.__file__` returns `C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\google_api_python_client-1.1-py2.7.egg\oauth2clie‌​nt\tools.pyc`. Can we uninstall `1.1` version?

Comment: Yes; see the second answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231688/how-do-i-remove-packages-installed-with-pythons-easy-install

Comment: I am not sure that I understand what is described on the second answer. I am trying to do that with `easy_install.py -m`. Because I am a Windows user can you tell me which folder/file to load? Is this approach correct?

Comment: @Thoth: delete `google_api_python_client-1.1-py2.7.egg` from `C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\`. Edit the file `easy-install.pth` in than same folder and remove any references to the `google_api_python_client-1.1-py2.7.egg` egg; if there is no reference to `google_api_python_client-1.2-py2.7.egg` in that file, change the references from 1.1 to 1.2

Comment: I realised that in the `site-packages` there was only `oauth2client-1.1-py2.7`. I thhought that via `easy_install.py --upgrade google-api-python-client` the `oauth2client-1.2-py2.7` would installed. Whatever, I installed manulally `oauth2client-1.2-py2.7` from [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/downloads/list) and problem solved. Thanks for your time!