# when installing statsmodels, I get the following error:RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration

Tags: python, ubuntu-12.04, statsmodels

I have read a lot of posts about this error, and the reason I am posting this is because I get the error when trying to install statsmodels package, and not one of my programs.

how do I correct the error when installing a package?

```
$ sudo pip3 install statsmodels
Downloading/unpacking statsmodels
  Downloading statsmodels-0.5.0.tar.gz (5.5MB): 5.5MB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_root/statsmodels/setup.py) egg_info for package statsmodels
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip_build_root/statsmodels/setup.py", line 463, in <module>
        check_dependency_versions(min_versions)
      File "/tmp/pip_build_root/statsmodels/setup.py", line 109, in check_dependency_versions
        from scipy.version import short_version as spversion
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/__init__.py", line 124, in <module>
        pkgload(verbose=SCIPY_IMPORT_VERBOSE,postpone=True)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/numpy/_import_tools.py", line 177, in __call__
        for package_name in self._get_sorted_names():
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/numpy/_import_tools.py", line 114, in _get_sorted_names
        for name in depend_dict.keys():
    RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

  File "/tmp/pip_build_root/statsmodels/setup.py", line 463, in <module>

    check_dependency_versions(min_versions)

  File "/tmp/pip_build_root/statsmodels/setup.py", line 109, in check_dependency_versions

    from scipy.version import short_version as spversion

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/__init__.py", line 124, in <module>

    pkgload(verbose=SCIPY_IMPORT_VERBOSE,postpone=True)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/numpy/_import_tools.py", line 177, in __call__

    for package_name in self._get_sorted_names():

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/numpy/_import_tools.py", line 114, in _get_sorted_names

    for name in depend_dict.keys():

RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/statsmodels
```

Reading the suggested response, I ran:

```
sudo pip3 install numpy --upgrade
Requirement already up-to-date: numpy in /usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages
Cleaning up...
```

Uninstalled matplotlib and numpy and then upon installing it again, I get the following message:

```
sudo pip3 install matplotlib
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): matplotlib in /usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy>=1.5 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): python-dateutil in /usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/python_dateutil-2.2-py3.2.egg (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): tornado in /usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyparsing>=1.5.6 in /usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/pyparsing-2.0.2-py3.2.egg (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): nose in /usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six in /usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/six-1.7.2-py3.2.egg (from python-dateutil->matplotlib)
Cleaning up...
```

For numpy, the reinstall returns the following:

```
sudo pip3 install numpy
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
Cleaning up..
```

.

Comment: The error is when importing scipy. What's your version of scipy? Maybe you need to update scipy. Try `import scipy` or `import scipy.stats`.

Comment: I installed scipy from the package center in Ubuntu 12.04, so it is the default version. I wrote the following code and ran it `from scipy import stats`, but it gave me the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug hitting numpy in Python 3.*. It seems to have been fixed in the source, but I don't know if it has found itself to a release yet.

Try upgrading numpy before installing statsmodel.

In Python 2.*, the .keys() function would return a list, but in 3.* it returns an iterator, hence the reason to the bug.

Comment: I tried upgrading it (updated my post with the message). Regardless I tried to install statsmodels again, and the error persists

Comment: It looks like the fix is scheduled for numpy 1.9.
If you can't wait, have a look at was made for the bug fix here and simply change your files to match it.
https://github.com/numpy/numpy/commit/5025c40965fa5fb2b591f07c152b966dc7b730f0
If you don't make any other changes, you should be perfectly fine.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I am confused as to how previously it was fine and then someone on this site suggested I do a matplotlib upgrade (this was in response to my last post querying about show() not working) and after running that, this mess-up happened. I am still learning so I don't think I know how to change the correct files, but I will look out for the updated version.

Comment: Seems to me the issue is that upgrading matplotlib forced an upgrade of its dependencies (numpy). The latest version of numpy introduced this bug. With pip you can set the version you want to install, so what I would do is uninstall both matplotlib/numpy and install older versions of both libraries. That, or use python2 :)

Comment: I just did `sudo pip3 uninstall matplotlib` and similarly for `numpy`. I went back to run `'sudo pip3 install matplotlib` and `numpy` and I updated my post with the message I am getting.

Comment: and once again, you helped me fix this problem. thanks again.