# Updated setuptools using easy_install -U, now there is a distribution error

Tags: python, setuptools, easy-install

I updated setuptools using:

`easy_install -U setuptool`

This ran fine. I then realized I did not want to use the most recent version of setuptools and deleted `setuptools-18.3.2-py2.6.egg` file from `/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages`. After I did this I am getting the following errors when trying to install anything using easy_install shown below.

```
easy_install ReviewBoard-1.7.6-py2.6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/easy_install", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2659, in <module>
    parse_requirements(__requires__), Environment()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 546, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: setuptools>=0.7
```

Comment: I have tried running the easy_install -U distribute as well, same result

Answer (score 0):

Looks like ReviewBoard needs setuptools as a dependency. When you ran `easy_install ReviewBoard-1.7.6-py2.6`, it would have detected that this dependency is already installed but actually it wasn't.

One reason could be that deleting the .egg file was not the complete process of getting rid of a package installed with easy_install. You also need to remove the corresponding line from site-packages/easy-install.pth. Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1233282/4045754