# How to see Python Packages in Finder

Tags: macos, python-2.7

I have been trying to delete some Python packages, and found the path for them in the Terminal, and it gave me /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages, but for some reason I went into Library in my Finder and Frameworks wasn't there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove packages installed with Python's easy\_install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231688/how-do-i-remove-packages-installed-with-pythons-easy-install)

Answer (score 1):

You're looking at your user Library (`~/Library`), not your system library where python is installed (`/Library`).

In Finder, press <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> and then enter `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages`, but it's probably best to just [uninstall your packages completely and correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231688/how-do-i-remove-packages-installed-with-pythons-easy-install).