# Can't uninstall Tornado with pip

Tags: python, tornado

I installed Tornado
sudo easy_install tornado

then it got a lot of syntax errors.

I want to uninstall Tornado
pip uninstall tornado

Then it asks: 
Uninstalling tornado-6.0.1:
  Would remove:
    /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tornado-6.0.1-py2.7-macosx-10.13-intel.egg
Proceed (y/n)?

I typed y,

then it says

Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-18.0-py2.7.egg/pip/_internal/basecommand.py", line 141, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
...

Comment: follow the solution form [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231688/how-do-i-remove-packages-installed-with-pythons-easy-install)

Comment: Thank you so much, @prashantrana

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove packages installed with Python's easy\_install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231688/how-do-i-remove-packages-installed-with-pythons-easy-install)

Answer (score 0):

Try to uninstall it with "easy_install -m tornado"

Comment: error: can't create or remove files in install directory

The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
installation directory:

    [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/test-easy-install-878.write-test'

Comment: try it with sudo